# Coffee Table Trig (Finding angles when working with wider boards)

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I am building a coffee table in my garage and I've decided to make the legs out of criss-crossing 1x4 boards. The dimensions of the crossing support formed by the two boards needs to be exactly 18 inches tall by 15 inches wide. The problem is to figure out the angle to cut the boards at. I have the start to a solution below which involves solving a 4th order polynomial, and I want to make sure I did this the easiest/correct way.

Below is my sketch of the solution showing 1 diagonal support and the solution for how long the diagonal edge of the support needs to be (variable x).

**Work has error, see edit below.**

[image: Page 1]

[image]

So, now that I have x, it is trivial to solve for everything else. A free trial of Mathematica gave me the solution at the end. 4.737 looks like a reasonable length (4.95 is the solution if the angle were 45, so this passes the common-sense check). But that whole solution looks overcomplicated. Is there a simpler way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

The error in the above paper work is that I mix up the theta and phi angles in the second drawing (the blow up of the bottom corner that has 3.5 as the hypotenuse). This leads to incorrect sine and cosine substitutions. If you swap the angles you will end up with a 2nd order polynomial to solve at the end, and get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't checked your work, but by coincidence, I needed to work out the same question some time back. Here's the general diagram, in the hope it's useful to posterity:

[image: Cutting a diagonal cross brace]

Comment: Yes this is correct. My scanned work has an error though. I mixed up cosine and sine at the very beginning, but after fixing error my solution and this equation get the same answer. sin(theta) = 0.855